# Show scrollbars if SVG elements overflows their container

Tags: svg, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I have an embedded SVG with dynamic content inside, which may grow in all directions.
This content may be grow bigger than the fix sized container around.
My expected behavoir is, to show scrollbars, if any element inside the SVG needs more place than the container provides.

See the [following simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/sGN2Q/6/):

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="overflow: auto; position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 60px; background-color: gray; height: 200px; width: 300px;">
        <svg style="height: 190px;">
                <rect x="-50" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="red"></rect>
        </svg>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the way to do this?
Is it really true, there is no concept in SVG to support such behavoir?
Any suggestions how to do it right "by hand"?

Answer (score 2):

Svg does'nt support auto resizing to inside elements of itself.
So, you should resize manually the svg graphic to be able to scroll by outer svg element.

```
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
var bbox = svg.getBBox();
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height]);
svg.width.baseVal.valueAsString = bbox.width;
svg.height.baseVal.valueAsString = bbox.height;
```